# consul exec doesn't do anything

Tags: consul

I've used Hashicorps' example `docker-compose` to start a 3-server / 3-client cluster of Consul.

I just wanted to see how `consul exec` works:

```
consul members
Node          Address          Status  Type    Build  Protocol  DC   Segment
b9e4dbaa35ac  172.18.0.7:8301  alive   server  1.3.0  2         dc1  <all>
dac0d326a3c2  172.18.0.4:8301  alive   server  1.3.0  2         dc1  <all>
efd58b702d4c  172.18.0.5:8301  alive   server  1.3.0  2         dc1  <all>
30303321aefc  172.18.0.3:8301  alive   client  1.3.0  2         dc1  <default>
a91e25b36145  172.18.0.6:8301  alive   client  1.3.0  2         dc1  <default>
b0f7559d3bea  172.18.0.2:8301  alive   client  1.3.0  2         dc1  <default>
```

Then, I tried calling in all kinds of combinations:

```
consul exec -node {hash} ip a
consul exec 'ip a'
consul exec -shell 'ip a'
```

etc.

No errors, but no output either, always:

```
0 / 0 node(s) completed / acknowledged
```

I couldn't find any examples on the internet.  The documentation is less than unhelpful.

---

Found this: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/consul-tool/zE4G9ixWq60

Which basically says that `consul exec` is an un-feature...

Answer (score 3):

OK, in case you were wondering the same, here's how I solved it:

```
consul agent -hcl 'disable_remote_exec=false' ...
```